# How to get a Stream from in-memory Image?

Tags: .net, image, stream, openxml

I have an in-memory `Image`, I need to get a `Stream` from it to write into an OpenXML document. Can someone please point me to the correct method.

Comment: And would that be System.Windows.Controls.Image, System.Drawing.Image, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image or maybe another class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an overload of the `Save` method that takes a `Stream` as a parameter. To create a stream that exists in-memory, you can use `MemoryStream` type. Something like this should work:

```
// Create new memory stream and save the image
var ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// Seek to the first byte in the stream, so that other classes who
// use it will start reading from the beginning
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrgin.Begin);
```

Now you can pass the newly created stream `ms` to other objects (e.g. to save it in `OpenXML`). See also:

- [Image.Save method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx) at MSDN

Answer (score 1):

I'd fix a few things:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat); // Save it in the original format of the image
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Fixed typo
```